# How do I Import cv2 error on Spyder (Python 3.9)?

Tags: opencv, import, ipython, spyder, macos-big-sur

I downloaded OpenCV via terminal on MacOs BigSur with the following command:

`brew install open cv`

However, when I try `import cv2` IPython console on Spyder gives me the following error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'opencv'`

I have Python 3.9.7 and OpenCV version is 4.5.4_4

I appreciate any tips on how to solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: did you literally install `cv` and `open`? did you notice the space?

Comment: Thanks--I typed `opencv` but that did not work. In the end, I used `pip install opencv-python` command over the terminal and that solved the problem.